# MySQL to SQL Server Migration and Hibernate/Spring MVC

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, hibernate, spring-mvc, porting

We are migrating a database from MySQL to SQL Server.  The migration is pretty straight forward and can be done quite quickly.  The project using the existing MySQL database is using Hibernate within Spring MVC.  If I migrated the database to SQL Server, and updated the dialect on the Spring MVC side, should the project just work without any other changes to Hibernate queries?  Or do we have to make changes to every database call in the data access layer in Spring MVC?  I guess I'm trying to find out where the pain points will be and if we could run into any huge issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on dependency of your application on database features, are you using stored procedures? MySQL special functions in your HQLs? and ... If you have not used any, I believe everything will go fine

Comment: No stored procedures are being used, just raw HSQL.